# average value when comparing each element with each other element in a list

Tags: math, statistics

I have number of strings (n strings) and I am computing edit distance between strings in a way that I take first one and compare it to the (n-1) remaining strings, second one and compare it to (n-2) remaining, ..., comparing until I ran out of the strings.

Why would an average edit distance be computed as sum of all the edit distances between all the strings divided by the number of comparisons squared. This squaring is confusing me.

Thanks,
Jannine

Comment: probably not the number of comparisons is squared, but the number of strings is compared to produce the number of comparisons. Is your diff commutative? I mean is "Grandma" to  "Granddame" the same distance as "Granddame" to "Grandma"? Then you should be able to skip half of the comparisons.

Comment: you are right, it is divided by (number of strings compared to produce the number of comparisons)^2. Edit distance between Grandma" to "Granddame"  is the same distance as "Granddame" to "Grandma". Are you saying that because of commutative property of edit distance (I am using Levenshtein algorithm) I need to divide number of comparisons by (number of strings compared to produce the number of comparisons)^2 in order to get an average.

Comment: If Tom, Sarah and Adam meet, they shake hands. You do a handshake between Tom and Sarah, Tom and Adam, Sarah and Tom, Sarah and Adam and Adam and Tom, Adam and Sarah in your description. That is no 3*3 (so square of number of people), but 3*2 (so `n * (n-1)`). I say if Tom Greeted Sarah then Sarah does not need to greet Tom again, so I would say use `n*(n-1)/2` as denominator and compare every string only once with the other.

Comment: hmmm, these are the strings I am comparing                           AS_PATH: 6893 3303 3561 6453
AS_PATH: 6893 8938 3549 13609 13609 13609
AS_PATH: 6893 8938 1 297
AS_PATH: 6893 3303 1 6453 4755 17439 17488
AS_PATH: 559 3303 2914 2497 4774 4651 10025
AS_PATH: 513 8918 1299 12457 8216
AS_PATH: 513 209 6453 4651 10025
AS_PATH: 513 209 3356 15412 8966 8966 8961 9557
AS_PATH: 513 5511 4766 4766 9866
AS_PATH: 513 10764 6509 297

Comment: hmmm, above are the strings I am comparing (ignore the AS_PATH part in the string) so what I am doing is taking first one and find the edit distance between it and the rest of them, In this case I find  9 values of edit distance. Next string in line I compare with remaining 8 strings, and the second to last string I compare with the last one. That way I have 9+8+7+...+1 values for edit distance. So if I divide it by (10x9)/2 it would work?

Comment: Ah, exactly, you do exactly the `half as much` version, so it makes `(10x9)/2` values! Right!

Comment: And if you have `547` strings, you would have `547 * 546 / 2` comparisons and thus divide the whole sum by `547*546/2`.

Comment: I am looking at the piece of code where someone found average edit distance as number of comparisons divided by numbers of string squared. So you think that is absolutely nonsense? Average computed as you suggested differs quite a bit. So I was wondering if there are other ways of computing averages. all your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: One could make a quite simple code with comparing each string with each string (even itself), adding the distances, and then divide by square number of strings. But try calculating the average distance of your sample set with a small script or program, and then compare to the other one's output. But `Number` of comparisons sounds very wrong, if any it should be sum of distances.

Comment: Sorry it is sum of distances of course :). It has been a long night..What I am doing now is comparing 29 strings by hand, believe it or not. And by the morning :) I will have something to compare against the result of this code that seems suspicious.

Comment: Just give the 29 strings, don't do it by hand. The sum of distances divided by the square of numbers is a close enough average with 29 Strings.

Comment: I know it's a waste of time but I already finished two strings...27 more to go...and numbers of comparisons are going down as well :)

Comment: I would use python or javascript, as in https://github.com/gf3/Levenshtein/tree/master/lib, but I have no public server now to help. :-( I wish success! But just take the result from program, multiply it by 29*29 and divide by 29*28. That should be correct. Just double-check with a 4-String-Example, there take the result from program, multiply with 16 and divide by 4*3  = 12

Comment: thank you. your kindness will be remembered.

Comment: If my answer below is a bit helpful, you could upvote or accept it as answer. But that you can do later, now finish your work.

Comment: my reputation is not allowing me to upvote..but I accepted the answer :). 22 more to go...slow...

Comment: I hope it did not take forever and you make no error with 392 distances. Sorry for not helping more. And thanks for the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those things are getting easier to understand if done by hand with pen and paper for a small example.

If you have the 7 Strings named `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`f`,`g`, then the simplest version would

- Compare `a` to `b`, `a` to `c`, ... , `a` to `g` (this are 6)
- Compare `b` to `a`, `b` to `c`, ... , `b` to `g` (this are 6)
- `. . .`
- Compare `g` to `a`, `g` to `b`, ... , `g` to `f` (this are 6)

So you have 7*6 or `n*(n-1)` values, so you divide by nearly `7^2`. **This is where the square comes from**. Maybe you even compare `a` to `a`, which should bring a distance of `0` and increase the values to `7*7` or `n*n`. But I would count it a bit as cheating for the average distance.

You could double the speed of the algorithm, just changing it a small bit

- Compare `a` to `b`, `a` to `c`, ... , `a` to `g` (this are 6)
- Compare `b` to `c`, ... , `b` to `g` (this are 5)
- Compare `c` to `d`, ... , `b` to `g` (this are 4)
- `. . .`
- Compare `f` to `g` (this is 1)

That is following good ol' Gauss `7*6/2`, or `n*(n-1)/2`.

So in Essence: Try doing a simple example on paper and then count your distance values.

Since **Average** is still and very simply the same as ever:

```
sum(values) / count(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have somewhere an answer that seems to come with a squared factor -which I'll take as n^2, where n is the number of strings (not the number of distinct comparisons, which is n*(n-1)/2, as +flaschenpost points to ). It would be easier to give you a more precise answer if you'd exactly quote what that answer is.

From what I understand of your question, it isn't, at least it's not the usual sample average. It is, however, a valid estimator of central tendency with the caveat that it is a biased estimator.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator.

Let's define the sample average, which I will denote as X', by
X' = \sum^m_i X_i/N

IF N=m, we get the standard average. In your case, this is the number of distinct pairs which is m=n*(n-1)/2. Let's call this average Xo.

Then if N=n*n, it is 
X' = (n-1)/(2*n) Xo

Xo is an unbiased estimator of the population mean \mu. Therefore, X' is biased by a factor f=(n-1)/(2*n). For n very large this bias tends to 1/2.

That said, it could be that the answer you see has a sum that runs not just over distinct pairs. The normalization would then change, of course. For instance, we could extend that sum to all pairs without changing the average value: The correct normalization would then be N = n*(n-1); the value of the average would still be Xo though as the number of summands has double as well.